# Show confirm box from code-behind and use the response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im calling a c# method using jquery ajax.

I would like to show a confirm box when ive reached a certain point in the c# method, and make use of the confirm box result in the method. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question, might help you : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892068/get-the-return-confirm-popbox-value-in-asp-net-c-sharp**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. You could split your method into 2 methods and call them one after the other. This way you have the possibility to show a confirm box before callnig the second method.