# how to call java-script on client click using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am trying to ask the user "are you sure you want to submit" on button click if they select yes then i want to call another java-script function, how can i do that?

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClientClick="return confirm('are you sure you want to submit?');" OnClick="btn_submit_Click"> 
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Submit
      </asp:LinkButton>
```

i also want to call this method: return validate() once the OnClient event is fired:

```
OnClientClick="return validate()"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the return confirm popbox value in asp .net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892068/get-the-return-confirm-popbox-value-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you write a single function that confirms from the user and then fires the validate function?

```
function Confirm(){

if (confirm("are you sure you want to submit?") == true) {
    Validate();
} else {
    //
}
}
```